# Getting "A fatal error occurred while creating a TLS client credential. The internal error state is 10011" running IdentityServer4 in Production mode

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

My ASP.NET Core 6 Web API uses IdentityServer4 as idp. It works just fine when the idp runs in development mode.

When I set the idp to run in Production mode by setting the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` in `web.config`, the idp always fails to start.

The system event shows the error:

> A fatal error occurred while creating a TLS client credential. The internal error state is 10011

The strange thing is that, if it is TLS related, why does development mode work, but Production doesn't, everything else being exactly the same? Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
Here is the web.config file. As you can see, the Production mode is set, and this is when the IDS false. It works fine when it is set to Development.
[image]

Comment: Have you provided and setup a valid HTTPS certificate in production? HTTPS is  requirement for IdentityServer to work, otherwise you will have cookie problems.

Comment: Yes, we do. We run the app in Development mode under HTTPS all the time and without any issues. It's just when we switch to Production mode we get the error.

Comment: can you share some code? web.config??? are you using IIS?

Comment: Thanks Tore for looking into this. I have shared my web.config above. What else should I share?

Comment: why is the process path to \bin\debug...? why deploy debug builds to production? what does the ASP.NET Core log say?

Comment: Sorry Tore, my bad, I took the web.config from our developent environment by mistake, instead of from the build result in the Publish folder. I have just updated the attachment above. None of the log files contains anything about the error.

Comment: what HTTPS port are you using in production? How have you added the certificate? to IIS?  I would run this test, to verify your HTTPS TLS/cihper configuration https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/   , perhaps its to strict or not valid?

Comment: We use port 6015 for HTTPS in our testing for Production environment. We have tested on multiple servers and they all came back with the same result. There are other apps on some of those servers, and they run fine under HTTPS.

Comment: I would lower the log level to verbose to see what the ASP.NET Core logs say, if the traffic goes that far, or if the request is stops in IIS.